# symfony 2.8 InvalidArgumentException in XmlFileLoader.php line 281

Tags: php, symfony

i putted my application on line but i have this error :

InvalidArgumentException in XmlFileLoader.php line 281:

Unable to parse file "/***/***/***/***/htdocs/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/web.xml".

my app_dev.php :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

// If you don't want to setup permissions the proper way, just uncomment the following PHP line
// read http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup for more information
//umask(0000);

// This check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to production servers.
// Feel free to remove this, extend it, or make something more sophisticated.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
//|| isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
|| !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1', 'my IP')) || php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server')
) {
header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check    '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
Debug::enable();

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: I don't think posting your app_dev.php will help, can you post the Resources/config/web.xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in the version of PHP it needs 5.5 or heigher because i host my application in a site of hosting free